# Using \pgfmathparse directly in another expression

Tags: tikz-pgf, variable

I can store `\pgfmathresult` in a variable `\y` and then pass the variable to another expression (`\pgfpoint`):

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\displ{2}
    \pgfmathparse{\displ + 2}\edef\y{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfpoint{0}{\y}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Can I construct the `\pgfpoint` directly:

```
\pgfpoint{0}{??? \pgfmathparse{\displ + 2}}
```

Comment: In TeX lingo, you are asking *if `\pgfmathparse` is expandable* and no it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious thing works. (The line is very short because if you don't specify the unit, the unit will be `pt`.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\displ{2}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{\displ}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{\displ+2}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```